Screen randomly blanks and app icons randomly appear really small on ubuntu 24.04
I currently have Ubuntu 24.04 running on my laptop with the following specs:

Laptop Name: ASUS X541UAK/ F541UAK
CPU :Intel Core i5-7200U
GPU (intergrated) :Intel HD Graphics 620 (kbl GT2)
Monitor: HP LE 2201w (connected via VGA port)

***I removed the internal laptop display...eyes not so good...was breaking my back and neck...not enough usb ports)
Occassionally the display blanks for a second as if it is disconnecting and reconnecting. This happens when I am actively using the computer. App icons randomly appear small (see attached screenshot). Cables have been inspected and are in excellent condition. To rule out hardware failure as a cause I installed and ran Windows 10 for a few days and even played some games for hours without any issues. This never occured on Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04. Logging out and back in, switching between xorg and wayland does not fix the issue. The issues occurs randomly. I have been unable to find out what exactly  triggers it.
*Screenshot of app icons appearing small

*Screenshot of app icons displaying properly

EDIT
Results of sudo lshw -c video
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1680,1050
       resources: irq:134 memory:ee000000-eeffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff


Run lshw -c video in a terminal, add the result with editing your question.

I have added the resluts of lshw -c video

I think this is is your problem https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2064189 check it and if it is add yourself to the bug, so that you get an email when something comes up, and also adding yourself increases the chance that they will solve the issue faster.

I followed the suggested answer from the bug report and I have not had and problems since then.

I fixed the issue by following the solution from this bug report.
These are the steps I followed:

sudo nano /etc/default/grub
Added the lineGRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.enable_dc=0 intel_idle.max_cstate=2"
Saved the file. Ctrl+O and Ctrl+X
Updated grub: sudo update-grub
And then rebooted.

